# Multithreaded WebServer

Tags: java, client-server

Hi I`m trying to create a Multithreaded Webserver 
I have referred 
[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4910033/java-multithreaded-web-server-not-recieving-multiple-get-requests)
[Link 2](http://www.seas.gwu.edu/~cheng/6431/Projects/Project1WebServer/webserver.html)

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
public class WebServer {

    ServerSocket server;
    public WebServer() {
        try {
            server=new ServerSocket(3000);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("exc in const "+ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
    Socket client;
    BufferedReader br;
    Thread t=new Thread(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try{
                        System.out.println(br.readLine());                    
                    }
                    catch(Exception e){
                        System.out.println("exc is "+e);
                    }
                } 
            });
    public void RUN(){

         while(true){
            try {
                client=server.accept();
                   System.out.println(client.getPort());
                if(client!=null){
                   r=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
                   t.start();
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("ex is "+ex.getMessage());
            }
         }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        WebServer webserver=new WebServer();
       try {
                webserver.RUN();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("main "+e);
        }          
    }
}
```

In the above code I keep getting a thread Illegal Access Exception so why do i keep getting this exception
I want to open Multiple tabs in browser and open localhost:3000 then the Server Must print the http request and port number but this happens only for first Client and not the others it shows illegalThreadAccess Exception and the Program terminates

Will greatly Appreciate if any pages are there that tell how to display some content in a Webbrowser.

Comment: would help if you add the stacktrace of the exception

Comment: Hi I`m using trycatch block so I only get the Message  of Exception we get a stack trace only if program execution is stopped due to an exception that is not caught rite?

Comment: I would start by implementing a simple producer/consumer pattern. Not being rude, but I think a webserver might be a little beyond your abilities.

Comment: @Boris how do i accept then Connection From multiple clients then? I`m a newbie so wat must be done

Comment: @Boris beyond abilities or not I must give a try

Comment: I'm not saying don't try, I'm saying try something simpler first to get an understanding of scope and thread safety before you attempt your web server. P.S. there is a little method in `Exception` that you can use to print the full stacktrace, [`printStackTrace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#printStackTrace(java.io.PrintStream))

Comment: java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException
 at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:682)
 at WebServer.RUN(WebServer.java:41)
 at WebServer.main(WebServer.java:52)

Comment: You're not spawning new threads, your simply calling `start` on the same `Thread` again and again. The second time this throws and exception because the thread has already started.

Comment: please could you tell me what happens to a thread after it finishes executing the run method I thought that each time the run method finishes executing the thread aborts after that and a new thread is created

Comment: @ Boris I have moved the Anonymous inner Class implementation before the t.start the Exception is no longer thrown so a new thread object is created each time

Answer (score 1):

As you can read in the documentation of the [Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start%28%29) class method start() throws 
*IllegalThreadStateException if the thread was already started.*

In your code, you create thread only once, and you try to run it multiple times.

How to fix? Before line:

```
t.start();
```

you should create new thread

```
Thread t=new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try{
                    System.out.println(br.readLine());                    
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    System.out.println("exc is "+e);
                }
            } 
        });
```

**Edit:** About questions in comments. When you start thread, it starts to live its own live. You can eg. wait for terminating by invoking `join()` method on the thread object. The specification of the `Thread` class says how it's working and it says that you cannot rerun it.

Comment: Hi faramir In the above comments i have mentioned that i corrected the issue as Boris also suggested the same thanks I will appreciate if you can tell as to how i can display ahtml page in the webbrowser

Comment: so does it terminate after finishing its run method?

Comment: Try to open http://localhost:3000/ page in the browser, **but** remember that browsers use the HTTP protocol for communication and if you would like to see the html content you need to reply correct HTTP response (headers and data). Moreover, your "webserver" needs also better processing data - you start new thread and immediately after you can accept new connection and start new thread, but the `br` could be changed in the meantime - two threads will _fight_ for the data to read...

Comment: won`t br be unique for each thread each thread has a br wrapped around a socket outputstream each a has a separate TCP connection am i rite or ami i totally worng?

Comment: You have only one instance of `WebServer` class, and for that one instance you have field `br`, so everything is _shared_. Probably, you would like to create new class that implements `Runnable`, and create new instance for every request, and in that class you should set the `br` and start new thread using the new class object. Of course that is not the best way to write server application, but the simplest one.